# Datetime behaviour TypeError: parser() missing 1 required positional argument:

Tags: python, pandas

I have modified this

```
def parser(x):
    return datetime.strptime('190'+x, '%Y-%m')
```

because my monthly date goes from 2002-2017

```
def parser(x,y):
    return datetime.strptime('20'+x+y, '%Y-%m')
```

When I run

```
s = read_csv('output.csv', header=0, parse_dates=[0], index_col=0, squeeze=True, date_parser=parser)
```

terminal output shows

```
site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 3030, in converter
    date_parser(*date_cols), errors='ignore')
TypeError: parser() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
```

And

```
miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 3039, in converter
    dayfirst=dayfirst),
  File "pandas/_libs/tslibs/parsing.pyx", line 434, in pandas._libs.tslibs.parsing.try_parse_dates
  File "pandas/_libs/tslibs/parsing.pyx", line 431, in pandas._libs.tslibs.parsing.try_parse_dates
TypeError: parser() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a212.py", line 8, in <module>
    series = read_csv('output.csv', header=0, parse_dates=[0], index_col=0, squeeze=True, date_parser=parser)
```

Something is wrong with positional arguments.What should I change?
EDIT

IF I TRY WITH ONE ARGUMENT IT DOES NOT WORK

```
line 362, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data '202002-01-15' does not match format '%Y-%m'
```

Data

```
Date, Price 
2002-01-15,3.1
2002-02-15,2.86
2002-03-15,3.37
2002-04-15,3.8
2002-05-15,3.78
2002-06-15,3.61
2002-07-15,3.49
2002-08-15,3.42
2002-09-15,3.71
2002-10-15,4.19
2002-11-15,4.35
```

Comment: I think `date_parser(*date_cols), errors='ignore')` is only passing in one column, colum [0] from your `parse_dates=[0]` argument - but the date_parser function you've defined expects 2 arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) states:

> **date_parser** : function, default None
>
> Function to use for converting a sequence of string columns to an
>   array of datetime instances. The default uses dateutil.parser.parser
>   to do the conversion. Pandas will try to call date_parser in three
>   different ways, advancing to the next if an exception occurs: 1) **Pass
>   one or more arrays (as defined by parse_dates) as arguments**; 2)
>   concatenate (row-wise) the string values from the columns defined by
>   parse_dates into a single array and pass that; and 3) call date_parser
>   once for each row using one or more strings (corresponding to the
>   columns defined by parse_dates) as arguments.

When the array (first column in your case) is passed as an argument, your `parser` function will be applied to each value in the column.

In other words, *only one argument* will ever be passed to your function. But your function requires 2 arguments (`x`, `y`).

You need to figure out exactly what logic you want to apply to the strings in your column and apply it in the form `f(x)`.

Given the data you provided, this should suffice:

```
from datetime import datetime

def parser(x):
    return datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d')

s = pd.Series(['2002-01-15', '2002-02-15', '2002-03-15'])
s.apply(parser)

# 0   2002-01-15
# 1   2002-02-15
# 2   2002-03-15
# dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: I should pass one array,but how to specify years range from 20 02-17?

Comment: first show us some data.. what do your strings in column 0 look like?